# Where should I put a fixed amount of dielectric to maximize the capacitance between two widely separated plates?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

Imagine that I have a capacitor made from two parallel finite plates, separated widely enough that there is a significant fringe field.  (Thus, the capacitance is not given exactly by $\epsilon_0 A/d$.)

I have a fixed amount of some dielectric material, which I will distribute within the region between the plates.  Qualitatively, how should I do this in order to maximize the final capacitance?  Should I form the dielectric into a cylinder, or should I choose some other shape such as one of these?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362893

Comment: If you're going to allow the surfaces to bend, you need to define your question a little more precisely. What is the constraint? (Is the volume of the dielectric material? Is it the distance between the plates at specific points? Is it the area of the plates? ... )

Comment: @JonathanJeffrey The surfaces remain flat and are not allowed to move or bend.  The constraint is the (constant) volume of the dielectric material.

Comment: @Thorondor Ah, I was viewing it from the sides. Thanks for editing the picture!

Comment: I think a fairly elegant answer can be found if you  give the problem cylindrical symmetry, and then impose a simple shape for the dielectric you place inside (e.g. an ellipisoid, such that [the depolarization factor is known](https://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/DepolarizationFactor.html)). Then you just need to calculate the field along the line of symmetry. Other than that, you have to calculate things, but there might be a general principle to help you along. Also, ignoring fringing fields, if the sample >= plate-width with constant thickness,the thickest sample clearly wins.